# When should we use jQuery append() and appendTo()?

Tags: jquery

I know about the append() and appendTo() functionality. But I am confused when to use which method, because both of this method do the same thing.

Is it differ in terms of performance ?

Comment: Did you read the manuals?

Comment: If you actually knew about their functionality you'd know that they don't do exactly the same thing. There are very obvious and important differences that dictate which one is appropriate, or at least easier, to use in any given situation.

Comment: if you know about the features your question has no logical

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to do with performance here, the both differs in the basis of returning the object.

If you want to return the object of appended element use [**`appendTo()`**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

If you want to return the object of element in which you have appended use **[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what value you want in return.

If you want the newly created objects reference to be returned then use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

If you want the object to which the values are appended then use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

It solely depends on the element you want to be returned:

If you want the created obeject go for .appendTo()
If you want parent object then use .append()